# Spatialite: insert polygons into multipolygon geometry column?

Tags: spatialite, multipolygons

I am using Spatialite (coming with QGIS 3.16).

I have a query that collects records to insert them into a table I created for this purpose.
I set the geometry type of the geometry column to MULTIPOLYGON :

```
CREATE TABLE parkings_combinés_lycées (
    identifiant_lycée VARCHAR(10), 
    surface_totale_m² FLOAT,
    "%_emprise_dans_parcelles_lycées" FLOAT );
```

However, inserting data (using a INSERT INTO .. SELECT .. query) fails with the error message :

```
parkings_combinés_lycées.geom violates Geometry constraint [geom-type or SRID not allowed]
```

I checked the records returned by the SELECT statement using the function ST_GeometryType and indeed some record have POLYGON geometries while others have MULTIPOLYGON geometries.

How do I solve this ?
Setting another geometry type in the CREATE TABLE ?

Answer (score 0):

I just found that the function *CastToMultiPolygon* does the trick !